# authentication systems in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

What are the most popular practices for developing authtentication systems that will are used for a simple login and logout system. Are developing custom authentication systems more popular or is it to use gems like devise, clearance, authlogic? The authentication system I am looking to build is pretty simple. So, I'd like to know what is the most popular solution when developing authentication systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can roll out a basic authentication with `bcrypt` ([good resource here](https://gist.github.com/thebucknerlife/10090014)). Bcrypt serves the purpose if your authentication system is not that complex and is limited to a few data models (say login to `/admin` section).

If you are looking for out of the box stable gem, [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is the standard choice with good community around it and the gem is stable with multiple releases and plays out well with other gems (admin gems like `rails_admin`, `activeadmin`) as it handles everything from data migrations to session controllers with few configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Devise is the far more popular than others. It will fit if you need thorough customizable authentication. And it's not so hard to use so you can choose it when you need some simple authentication solution.